# Google Maps polygons stuck at initial state of a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have a code that renders polygon when the map is ready and it works fine but I need to implement functionality where depending on a separate state, the polygons will be clickable or not. The problem is that when I set `clickable` prop to check for a condition, it is always the same value, no matter if that condition is different because polygons took the value from the moment they initially were rendered and thus ignore all other changes in the React component. Here's the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const forRetrun = []
      zones.forEach((z: ICreating) => forRetrun.push({ ...z, color: getColor(1) }))
      sections.forEach((s: ICreating) => forRetrun.push({ ...s, color: getColor(2) }))
      blocks.forEach((b: ICreating) => forRetrun.push({ ...b, color: getColor(3) }))
      pits.forEach((p: ICreating) => forRetrun.push({ ...p, color: getColor(4) }))

      console.log(forRetrun)

      forRetrun.forEach((p) => {
        // Create label for polygon
        const center = getCenter(p)
        const content = document.createElement('p')
        content.innerText = p.areaName
        content.className = 'white-text'
        // forRetrun.push({ id: 'creating', path: creating.path, color: getColor(creating.type) })

        if (loadedPolygons.current.some((lp) => lp.id == p.id + '_' + p.type)) {
          const foundIndex = loadedPolygons.current.findIndex((lp) => lp?.id == p.id + '_' + p.type)
          loadedPolygons.current[foundIndex].polygon.setMap(null)
          loadedPolygons.current[foundIndex].label.setMap(null)
          delete loadedPolygons.current[foundIndex]
        }
        loadedPolygons.current.push({
          id: p.id + '_' + p.type,
          label: new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
            position: { lat: Number(center.lat), lng: Number(center.lng) },
            map,
            content,
          }),
          polygon: new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: p.path,
            fillColor: p.color,
            map,
            strokeWeight: 0.5,
            clickable: !checkCreating(), /// <====== HERE 
          }),
        })
        loadedPolygons.current[loadedPolygons.current.length - 1].polygon.addListener('click', () => {
          handleGetInfo(p)
        }
        )
      })
    }
  }, [map, zones, sections, blocks, pits])
```

Here, the `checkCreating` function is supposed to check if others polygon is currently being drawn on a map and if so, every other polygon should be non clickable in order to allow user to click it and not enter its description but rather put a pin on a map but as I said, polygons run this function when I render them, see that condition is not fullfilled and no longer check for changes

Comment: I tried rerendering them each time something changes so but I get blinking each time

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this? A codesandbox would be great! Also, are you using any library for this?